# Why doens t the code get into the if statement? So confused

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop

it gets in the while loop but never into the if statement...

```
i = 0
x = ""
while True:
    if i == 1 | i == 2:
        x = x + ('*' * i) + ' '
        i += 1
        continue
    elif i > 2:
        break
    i += 1

print(x)
```

Comment: It appears you're using `|` which in python is a "bitwise or". You probably meant to use the word "or" instead (i.e. line 4 would be `if i == 1 or i == 2:`). Fix this and tell us if it works

Comment: Is it because of the [operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence).
`i==1 | i==2` is equivalent to  `( i == (1|i) ) == 2`.

Answer (score 1):

In your if statement you probably want to use the logical "or", i.e. `or` and not the "bitwise or", i.e. `|` operator.

Here is an overview of all operators in Python: https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#mapping-operators-to-functions

Answer (score 0):

Because of the [operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence),  with bitwise `or` you need to use brackets

```
if (i == 1) | (i == 2)
```

But you probably want to use logical `or`

```
if i == 1 or i == 2
```